# How to generate random integer that are random "enough"?

Tags: performance, random, probability, probability-density, probability-distribution

I'm trying to solve the [280th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1URtv.jpg) problem in Project Euler, and for this I have written the following simulation;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/* Directions

    1
2       3
    4
*/

int grid[5][5] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}
};

int InitPos[2] = {2, 2};

int MaxExp = 5000000;

bool Success = false;
int StepCount = 0;
int ExpNumber = 1;
int AntsBag = 0;
void Init();
void CarryFood(int * pos);
void LeftFood(int * pos);
bool checkMovability(int * pos, int direction);
bool moveToDirection(int pos[2], int direction);
bool checkSuccess();
void ShowResult();


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    timeval curTime;
    gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);
    int milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000;


    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    //timeTData*.txt corresponds to using "time(&t)" above 
    //milliData.txt corresponds to using "milli" variable above
    //timeTUnsigData*.txt corresponds to using "(unsigned)time(&t)" above

    printf("%% Experiment Number : %d \n", MaxExp);
    while(ExpNumber <= MaxExp)
    {
        Init();
        int pos[2];
        pos[0] = InitPos[0];
        pos[1] = InitPos[1];
        do{
            int direction = (rand() % 4) + 1;
            if (moveToDirection(pos, direction))
            {
                StepCount++;    
            }
            if (pos[1] == 4&&grid[pos[0]][4]==2&&AntsBag==0)
            {
                CarryFood(pos);
            }
            if (pos[1] == 0&&grid[pos[0]][0]==0&&AntsBag==2)
            {
                LeftFood(pos);
            }
            checkSuccess();
        }
        while(!Success);

        ShowResult();
        ExpNumber++;
    }   

    return 0;
}

void Init()
{
    Success = false;
    StepCount = 0;
    AntsBag = 0;
    int gridInit[5][5] = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            grid[i][j] = gridInit[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void ShowResult()
{
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
    */
    printf("%d %d\n", StepCount, ExpNumber);
}

void CarryFood(int * pos)
{
        AntsBag = 2;
        grid[pos[0]][4] = 0;
}

void LeftFood(int * pos)
{
        AntsBag = 0;
        grid[pos[0]][0] = 2;
}

bool checkMovability(int * pos, int direction)
{
    switch(direction)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            if(pos[1]==0){
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            if (pos[0]==0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            if (pos[0]==4)
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            if (pos[1]==4)
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("Wrong direction input is given!!\n");
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

bool moveToDirection(int * pos, int direction)
{
    if ( !checkMovability(pos, direction) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    switch(direction){
        case 1:
        {
            pos[1] -= 1;
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            pos[0] -= 1;
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            pos[0] += 1;
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            pos[1] += 1;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("I'm stunned!\n");
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool checkSuccess()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if (grid[i][0] != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //printf("Success!\n");
    Success = true;
    return true;
}
```

And the redirected the output to a *.txt file and find the expected value of the number of steps with the following octave code;

```
clear
load data.txt
n = data(:,1);

output_precision(15);

mean(n)

%% The actual data

%% milliData1 -> 430.038224000000
%% milliData2 -> 430.031745000000

%% timeTData1 -> 430.029882400000
%% timeTData2 -> 430.019626400000

%% timeUnsigData1 -> 430.028159000000
%% timeUnsigData2 -> 430.009509000000
```

However, even I run the exact same code twice I get different results, as you can see from the above results.(Note that, I have tried this with different srand(..) inputs for the reason I'm going to explain).

I thought that the reason for this is because how I generate a random integer between 1-4 for the random directions of the ant, because as far as I have been though, the probability distribution of this experiment should be the same as long as I repeat the experiment large number of time (in this particular case 5000000 times).

So my first question is that is it really the problem with the method of how I generate random integers ? If so, how can we overcome this problem, I mean how can we generate integer random enough so that when we repeat the same experiment large number of times, the expected value between those is smaller than these result that I have got ?

Comment: I suspect you are intended to solve this problem more by mathematics than by simulation. It may be feasible to construct a graph of states and analyze it to calculate the mean. However, offhand, I am not sure.

Comment: The input probably has a huge variance, say 100-1000, so 5m data points would only give you as much significance as you show (say, 430.03±0.02); the input randomness isn't likely to be the major problem. This is possible to solve without any randomness, though; search "markov chain expected number of steps" for undergrad-level material on the subject.

Comment: @Veedrac How do you know the variance of the input ? and how did you calculated that error bar ?

Comment: Not sure I can give a quick summary about the error bar in the comments here, but (very) roughly speaking you can just take the square root of the number of samples to get the relative significance, and multiply that by your value to get the absolute significance. I don't know if I checked the variance manually, but there things you can kind'a guess if you know how random walks work.

Comment: @Veedrac Ok, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{1, 4};

int randNumber = dist(gen);
```

This generates a more uniform distribution of values.